# Why won't my Minecraft PE world appear for Wifi multiplayer?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I wanted to play with my brother on the same wifi, but the world name wouldn't appear. Both of us have Multiplayer World and Broadcast to LAN turned on, but we can only change it from the title menu.

I did manage to get in once, but I couldn't after that. We are both on android. Help?

Comment: You should check if you and your brother have the same MCPE version, cause you didn't specify it.

Comment: And why you can only turn Broadcast to LAN on from the title screen? You can actually turn it on while you are in-game too!

Answer (score -1):

One of you may have an outdated version of MCPE. Check your store and see if there is an update available.